# actions of the buttons of the cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am working with the tableview in which i added 2 buttons on one cell. Below is the code which i used

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    tickbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    tickbtn.tag = 200+indexPath.row;
    [tickbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 30, 30);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tickbtn];
    NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)tickbtn.tag);

    crossbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    crossbtn.tag = 400+indexPath.row;
    [crossbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [crossbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    crossbtn.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 30, 30);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:crossbtn];
    NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)crossbtn.tag);

    return cell;
}
```

on the tickbtn and crossbtn i am applying following actions :-

```
-(IBAction)addshed:(UIControl *)sender
{
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-200 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[list_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *check1 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+200];
    UIButton *check2 = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+400];
    UIImageView *btnimg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:check1.currentBackgroundImage];
    //UIImageView *btnimg2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:check2.currentBackgroundImage];
    NSLog(@"SHED LIST subviews: %@", btnimg1.image);
    // Shed_data *sheddata  = [[Shed_data alloc] init];
    if (btnimg1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"]) {
        //btnimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"];
        [check1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_green.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [check2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addsheddata:sender];
        NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)tickbtn.tag);
    }
     else if (btnimg1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_green.png"])
     {
        [check2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-red.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [check1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self removesheddata:sender];

}


}
-(IBAction)removeshed:(UIControl*)sender
{
  //.…………………….. My functionality
}
```

but in both these cases i am getting the tag value of last cell only whenever i am pressing the buttons of the cell.
Please locate my error and help me out to solve it. Your help will be much appreciable.

Comment: Can you show your code of -(IBAction)addshed:(UIControl *)sender ??
How you are getting the tag value?

Comment: Please describe some more what will happened after your button action triggered and finished?

Comment: when i press the button of paticular cell it will change the color of the cell….

Comment: @user3131561 : It can be easily done with customCell. see my updated answer.

Comment: What is `list_table` ? from where you fetching `UITableViewCell` objects and where you used it ?

Comment: list_table is the table's object which i used in the xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one as working fine for me. I Just tested with my `Xcode 5`.

**Modification :**
1. I Create an `NSMutableArray` with the name of _objects (`_objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"thre", nil];`). and give it to my `UITableView`.

2.Give the tickBtn and crossBtn an different color so easily visible.

3.change the button pressed function to `UIControl` to `UIButton` like `-(IBAction)addshed:(UIButton *)sender` and when button pressed i catch the tag value and print it out on the console.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    tickbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    tickbtn.tag = 200+indexPath.row;
    [tickbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tickbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 30, 30);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tickbtn];
    NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)tickbtn.tag);

    crossbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    crossbtn.tag = 400+indexPath.row;
    [crossbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [crossbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    crossbtn.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 30, 30);
    [crossbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:crossbtn];
    NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)crossbtn.tag);

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)addshed:(UIButton *)sender   {
    NSLog(@"add shed %d",sender.tag);
}

-(IBAction)removeshed:(UIButton *)sender   {
    NSLog(@"remove %d",sender.tag);
}
```

**NEW QUESTION UPDATE**

```
Did you try with 10 or more cells and try with some continuous scroll?
```

And the result is

[image]
[image]

**As the Another Answer says**

```
[cell addSubview:crossbtn];// -------- Change here ---------
```

Let me clear this as i know about it.

The contentView is a subview of `UITableViewCell`. [please review this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) and here you can see there are actually 3 subviews in a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Are you sure in this line `[cell.contentView addSubview:tickbtn];`, button will add only one time to cell? In case scroll or Reuse cell?

Comment: @Mani as per the requirement it working fine. please review updated answer Young Man and thank you for the comment / discussion. Good luck

Comment: Did you try with 10 or more cells and try with some continuous scroll and also just give log to cell.contentview.subviews.count?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44474/discussion-between-mani-and-8unty)

Comment: @bunty ……………. i i did the updation in addshed function please have a look and tell if somthing is wrong in that ….

Comment: @user3131561 i am trying to helping you out but your question is not very much clear. please update it

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issue. It may be lead to this type of error.

```
Why do you add subviews again and again to your cell's content view.?
```

That is, for every `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` call, button will be add to cell. In case `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, your last  cell may reuse to any other cell while scroll. It will lead to your error. that is your cell will contain two button.(tag with last cell and tag with your current cell).

In this line `[cell.contentView addSubview:tickbtn];`, you have to do some change according to add once and also for crossbtn.

**Updation:** I have seen your updated question. My suggestion, better use custom cell. Use this link to [how to create custom cell.](http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/). Lot of confusion in your code. ex. in this line `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[list_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`, It will give unexpected. Don't call delegate method like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your button to cell subview not cell's contentview subview. So use this code....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
        tickbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        tickbtn.tag = 200+indexPath.row;
        [tickbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok_gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 30, 30);
        [cell addSubview:tickbtn];// -------- Change here ---------
        NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)tickbtn.tag);

        crossbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        crossbtn.tag = 400+indexPath.row;
        [crossbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-gray.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [crossbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeshed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        crossbtn.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 30, 30);
        [cell addSubview:crossbtn];// -------- Change here ---------
        NSLog(@"tickbtn tag %ld",(long)crossbtn.tag);

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine for `cellForRowAtIndexpath:`.
 Error might be in getting the tag value at button click. Try to change with this code:-

```
-(IBAction)addshed:(UIControl *)sender
{
    //.…………………….. My functionality

    int selectedRow1 = ((UIControl *)sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"No. %d", selectedRow1);

}
```